# undefined method `doorkeeper_for' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

I'm having an error with `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method`doorkeeper_for'`when I added`doorkeeper_for :all` in my Api::Controller. Here my sample controller. What do I am doing wrong?

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  doorkeeper_for :all

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Comment: And where is this method defined? Are you using some specific gem? `doorkeeper` gem does not define such a method.

Comment: I'm just add gem 'doorkeeper' on my gemfile and I followed railscast pro #353. When I come up with adding doorkeeper_for :all. Then I get above error.

Comment: It has to be hugely overdated now. Will post an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`doorkeeper_for` method has been removed from doorkeeper gem. Instead, do:

```
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
```

To resolve any other issue, always refer to the documentation: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

Comment: Cool. Thanks @BroiSatse!